# What does "result.second == false" mean in this code?

Tags: c++, vector

I came across this c++ code for counting frequency in a vector.

```
std::map<std::string, int> countMap;

// Iterate over the vector and store the frequency of each element in map
for (auto & elem : vecOfStrings)
{
   auto result = countMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(elem, 1));
   if (result.second == false)
      result.first->second++;
}
```

from https://thispointer.com/c-how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-vector/. I want to ask what does

`result.second == false` mean?

Comment: Honestly, it's strange why you only asked for help with the simplest line in the example you posted.

Comment: ... I apologize for being stupid.

Comment: I think you can find out yourself... First research what `std::map::insert` returns, [link for convenience](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). Then I hope you know what `== false `means.

Comment: Not "stupid", but you _should_ try to get into the habit of looking things up when you're unsure what they do!

Comment: I did look it up. But i didn't know that i couldn't have items with the same key in a map so having ```false``` there made no sense to me. And ```second``` made me think about the value in the map so comparing that value to false just confused me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `std::map` and the other non-multi associative containers only store unique items there is a chance that when you insert something into it it wont actually insert since it may already be present.  `insert` therefore returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>` where the bool will be true if the insert succeeded and false otherwise.

---

I would like to point out you can get rid of the if statement in the loop.  Because of how `operator[]` of a map works the loop can be replaced with

```
for (const auto & elem : vecOfStrings) // also added const here since we don't need to modify elem
{
   ++countMap[elem];
}
```

And now if `elem` exists then you increment the value and if it doesn't you added `elem` to the map and increment its value.

Comment: This is not equivalent to the original code. When no collision happens, the integer should be left 0.

Comment: @AndreySemashev The OP uses `countMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(elem, 1))` which sets the initial value to **1**

Comment: It is sad that `std::map::operator[]` was precisely designed for cases like this, and word counting even listed in examples on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at but people do not bother to look into documentation

Comment: IMHO the "yes-voters" on the committee that "designed" `std::map::operator[]` to allow for implicit insertion need a stern talking to.

Comment: @Slava Unfortunately cplusplus.com still gets a lot of traffic, shows up first in search results and it's example is lacking: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/

Answer (score 2):

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`.

`pair.first` is an iterator to the newly inserted element OR the element that was already in the map and prevented the insertion.
`pair.second` tells whether or not the insertion happened.

`result.second == false` is detecting the case where nothing was inserted into the map due to a key collision.

Note that with C++17, this can be written to be a bit more clear:

```
auto [itr, inserted] = countMap.insert({elem, 1});
if (!inserted) {
    itr->second++;
}
```

Comment: With C++11 whole loop can be rewritten as @NathanOliver shows in his answer, which is even more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or
>   to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting
>   whether the insertion took place.

`result.first` gives you the iterator to the element, while `result.second` tells you whether the element was actually inserted or did already exist.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) returns a pair where the second value indicates whether any insertion actually happened. If the value is `false`, this means no value was inserted into the map because a value with the same key already exists.

However, the code shouldn’t be written like this: comparing against boolean literals is a nonsensical operation. Instead you’d write

```
if (not result.second)
// or
if (! result.second)
```

Comment: What's "nonsensical" about it? It makes literally as much sense as your proposed alternatives. (And, subjectively, has the benefit of being more explicit/clear.)

Comment: Would be more interesting to propose `auto [newIt, wasInserted] = ...; if (!wasInserted)` so the variable names make sense

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It’s nonsensical because it’s redundant. If you write `x == false`, why not actually go one step further and write `(x == false) == true`, since `x == false` is *also* a boolean value. And obviously you wouldn’t stop there because the result of that is *also* a boolean value. In more formal terms, you’re needlessly using an un-normalised logical term.

Comment: "nonsensical" and "redundant" mean two different things. Also look up the Slippery Slope Fallacy. Nobody wrote the code you're talking about...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I didn’t claim they were identical. But the operation is nonsensical *because* it’s redundant. And my argument isn’t arguing from a slippery slope. It’s a reductio ad absurdum. The two are structurally similar but completely distinct.

Comment: Okay, I'll rephrase: whether something makes sense, and whether something is necessary, are entirely orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No. They *can* be orthogonal, but not in this case.

Comment: Okay, we'll agree to disagree.

Comment: What a shame. Redundant use of literal booleans is one of those pet peeves that I really want to see eradicated. A small annoyance, sure, but a completely unnecessary and trivially avoidable syntactic clutter.

Comment: Just because you personally want the usage to go away doesn't make it nonsensical. The standard literally defines it as sensical. This answer takes your own personal style opinion and portrays it as hard fact.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The standard also defines `int x = 0; x += 1; x -= 1;` and other such redundant operations as sensical (simply by virtue of permitting them and assigning semantics to them) yet I hope you’ll agree with me that this is a completely nonsensical operation in common parlance. It is outside the scope of the standard to define whether code is meaningful. — Apart from this, teaching best practices is fully part of Stack Overflows’s mission. Don’t belittle this widely established norm as a “personal style opinion”.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::map::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) returns a pair of iterator and a `bool`. The `bool` indicates whether the insertion actually took place. The code you listed seems to increment the mapped `int` if key collision happens on `insert`.